# Populate HTML form via REST

Tags: javascript, html, rest, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML form (twitter bootstrap). The user enters some fields and i would like to have some fields auto filled via REST call. Currently i have the REST call (to populate individual fields) mocked/hardcoded as as per below

```
<div class="widget-content nopadding">
<form id="my_wizard" class="form-horizontal" action="/rest/my-wizard-service"        novalidate="novalidate" method="post">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Customer ID</label>
<div class="controls">
<label class="control-label">GB02FFF30565</label>
</div>
</div>
....
```

how can I replace this line

```
<label class="control-label">GB02FFF30565</label>
```

with a RESTful call to retrieve the data "GB02FFF30565"?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to some details about your REST api...

Comment: Hi, it's a Java back end with rest interface ' /rest/customer service/getcustomerid'. The method accepts a cookie as a @queryparam and figures out the Id from server side map,  it the returns the result as json (in a 200 Response), joe:555 for ex...

Comment: for ex... a hard coded version of teh REST interface to return "1" as the customer Id

    `@GET
    @Produces("application/json")
 @Path("/customer/id") 
    public Response getCustomerID(@CookieParam("MyCookie") final Cookie cookie)throws IOException {
                                //get id and return in response
    return Response.ok("1").build();
  
  
 }`